# InStr : skip the first get

Tags: vba

I'm on VBA and using InStr to check if some paterns are in my file .txt but i don't care about the first patern that i get in all my files. How can i skip for all my loops the first that i get.

In entry i have a folder with some .txt files (with 2000/9000 lines), i have a list of symbols names, and i need to check if each symbol are here in each file and how many symbol each file have. This step is done now but the first appearance in the symbol file does not interest me since it just declares the symbol but it is not a symbol. So to count the number of symbols of this type in this.txt file I have to remove the first one I get

```
For i = 2 To Filepath_size

    Open Filepath(i) For Input As #IndexFile
    Debug.Print "Open file: "; Filepath(i)
        Do While Not EOF(IndexFile)
        Line Input #IndexFile, LineContent
        If (InStr(LineContent, LinePrefix)) Then          
            For Each SymbolName In rngSymbo
                If (InStr(LineContent, SymbolName)) Then            
                    Set SymbolLineIndex = Range("A:A").Find(SymbolName, lookat:=xlWhole)            
                    Cells(SymbolLineIndex.Row, i + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 
                    Cells(SymbolLineIndex.Row, i + 1).Value = Cells(SymbolLineIndex.Row, i + 1).Value + 1
                    Cells(SymbolLineIndex.Row, i + 1).Font.Size = 20  
                End If 
            Next SymbolName 
        End If
        Loop
Close #IndexFile
    Next i
```

I start VBA one week ago so i don't know at all if this is possible but can skip the first appearance of the symbol spotted by the InStr. For the moment my code counts me every time it meets the symbol, that is to say once too many times than necessary, and display this on a table on my sheet1

Comment: Posting this after the answer about using a counter... another option here is to define your rngSymbo having used `.Find()` to determine the first instance and use the range below that.

Comment: Thx Cyril for your comment but I don't know if I've been able to understand you well, I need the whole range of rngSymbo. I check in my hundred .txt files with the symbols one by one of rngSymbo symbol to see if it is present or not in this text file, and how many times it is present in this file. Currently my code returns me that such symbol is present 25 times, it should skip the first time it encounters this symbol in the .txt file and send me 24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Here is the example showing how to count each pattern occurrences in the text:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestSplit()

    Dim sSample As String
    Dim aSymbols()
    Dim sSymbol
    Dim a

    sSample = "abc789 def 123 defghi123 abc def 456 789 abc ghi abc 123def 123 456abc789"
    aSymbols = Array("abc", "123", "789")
    For Each sSymbol In aSymbols
        a = Split(sSample, sSymbol)
        Debug.Print "Symbol '" & sSymbol & "': " & UBound(a) & " occurances"
    Next

End Sub
```

**Initial answer**

Here is the example of simple function which allow to get n-th pattern occurrence position in the text:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Debug.Print GetNthInStr("678 abc 123 abc 456", "abc", 1)
    Debug.Print GetNthInStr("678 abc 123 abc 456", "abc", 2)

End Sub

Function GetNthInStr(sText As String, sPattern As String, lNumber As Long) As Long

    Dim i As Long

    GetNthInStr = 0
    For i = 1 To lNumber
        GetNthInStr = InStr(GetNthInStr + 1, sText, sPattern)
        If GetNthInStr = 0 Then Exit For
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: Thx for the answer ! I think this function can be perfect in my case! But I still have one more question. I don't want to get where in the.txt my symbol appears, but just if it appears, and how many times it appears.
For example in :
"678 abc 123 abc 456 abc 789 abc 123 abc 456"
My objective is to know that ABC appears 4 times (since I don't want to count the first time it appears)

Answer (score 1):

add a counter and then check if the counter is greater than 1

```
counter = 0
For i = 2 To Filepath_size

Open Filepath(i) For Input As #IndexFile
Debug.Print "Open file: "; Filepath(i)
    Do While Not EOF(IndexFile)
    Line Input #IndexFile, LineContent
    If (InStr(LineContent, LinePrefix)) Then          
        For Each SymbolName In rngSymbo
            If (InStr(LineContent, SymbolName)) Then   
                counter = counter + 1
                if counter > 1 then
                    Set SymbolLineIndex = Range("A:A").Find(SymbolName, lookat:=xlWhole)            
                    Cells(SymbolLineIndex.Row, i + 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 4 
                    Cells(SymbolLineIndex.Row, i + 1).Value = Cells(SymbolLineIndex.Row, i + 1).Value + 1
                    Cells(SymbolLineIndex.Row, i + 1).Font.Size = 20  
                end if
            End If 
        Next SymbolName 
    End If
    Loop
Close #IndexFile
Next i
```

Comment: I think you need to reset `counter=0` for each symbol, otherwise it retains the value from previous symbol values in hte `For Each SymbolName` loop. I'd probably use `counter` as a `Dictionary` keyed to `SymbolName` (without altering the general flow). Otherwise, the symbol loop should be outside the `While` loop, but I'm not sure that wouldn't introduce other errors.

Comment: I added the counter, but in fact it counts me up to 3025 without resetting it to 0 at each symbol. So I tried to put the counter = 0 in the loop just before the "Next SymbolName" But it remains at 0 and therefore nothing is displayed in my table because it doesn't execute the rest.